# Can I use a generic type as a key name in an object?

Tags: typescript

I have a function that I want to return as an interface, where the generic parameters of that function dictate the key name & value type.

I want to prevent (or at least minimize) the amount of repetition in the calling code, or "DRY".

Every attempt to use the generic type as an object key results in an error like "K only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.", which is understandable since that's just how typescript works. But I want to do this anyway :)

This is what I've got so far:

```js
function foo<K extends string, V>(name: K): Partial<{ [key in K]: V; }> {
  return { [name]: undefined } as Partial<{ [key in K]: V; }>;
}
```

This works, and can be called like so:

```js
foo<'bar', number>('bar');
```

See how it's neccesary to pass `'bar'` twice in order to make this work? That's what I'm trying to resolve.

Now, typescript will throw an error when either occurence of `'bar'` is a different string than the other, so it'll be guaranteed to work. But that's not the point. The point is that from the perspective of the caller, as it were, a string has to be passed twice and they have to be the same, which will feel arbitrary and will feel unneccesary.

So, I would love to be able to rewrite it into something like this:

```js
function foo<K extends string, V>(): Partial<{ [key in K]: V; }> {
  return { [K]: undefined } as Partial<{ [key in K]: V; }>;
}
foo<'bar', number>();
```

Now it gives the error I mentioned. The idea is that since `name` and `K` are required by the compiler to be identical, I should be able to leave `name` out and use `K` instead. But as I said, that's just not how typescript works, unfortunately.

This would also be a viable alternative:

```js
function foo<V, K extends string>(name: K): Partial<{ [key in K]: V; }> {
  return { [name]: undefined } as Partial<{ [key in K]: V; }>;
}
foo<number>('bar');
```

The idea here is that `K` is ommitted because it could be inferred from the given `name` parameter. But alas, that is not how typescript works, and it tells me the function requires 2 generic parameters. So I suppose this kind of type inference is not possible.

The question is, how *do* I solve it, preferably without compiler errors :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may consider currying.

Example:

```js
const foo = <V>() => <K extends string>(name: K): Partial<{ [key in K]: V }> =>
  ({ [name]: undefined } as Partial<{ [key in K]: V }>)
const a = foo<number>()('bar') // Partial<{bar: number;}>
```

Comment: And this works because... It's okay to leave out (infer) *all* generic params of a function, but not to leave out one of the two? Or is there another mechanism at play?

Comment: Yes either you provide them all or you let the compiler infer all generics. You may provide a generic with default type (e.g. <V, K extends string = string>(name: K)) but if you specify the type only for V the compiler will assume that K is the default type string and it's not what you want i.e. K will not be inferred from the name argument type. By currying you are splitting the generic constraints so you can apply them separately at each call.